# In d3 when I press a button to update the data in my bargraph the text doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I have created a set of data lists that are used to change the bargraph. However, because they don't share the same x and y values. They print new x values and y values of the bar graph on top of the old ones.

Here is an image of the problem, as you can see the x and y values are printing on top of each other:

[image: An image of the problem, as you can see the x and y values are printing on top of eachother.]

I would like to know how to fix this, by either making the values shift, or just hiding them and printing new ones. Whichever you suggest.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Add 2 buttons -->
<button onclick="update1(data1)">Global Temperature</button>
<button onclick="update2(data2)">Variable 2</button>
<button onclick="update3(data3)">Variable 3</button>
<button onclick="update4(data4)">Variable 4</button>
<button onclick="update5(data5)">Variable 5</button>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>


<script>

// create data_set


var data1 = [
   {group: "1850", value: -0.37, y: 1},
   {group: "1880", value: -0.23, y: 1},
   {group: "1900", value: -0.2, y: 1},
   {group: "1920", value: -0.25, y: 1},
   {group: "1940", value: 0.01, y: 1},
   {group: "1960", value: -0.05, y: 1},
   {group: "1980", value: 0.09, y: 1},
   {group: "2000", value: 0.29, y: 1},
   {group: "2019", value: 0.74, y: 1}
];

var data2 = [
   {group: "400,000", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "B", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "C", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "D", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "E", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "F", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "G", value: 0.09, y: 2},
   {group: "H", value: 0, y: 2},
   {group: "I", value: 0, y: 2}
];

var data3 = [
   {group: "A", value: 1, y: 1},
   {group: "B", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "C", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "D", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "E", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "F", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "G", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "H", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "I", value: 0, y: 1}
];

var data4 = [
   {group: "A", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "B", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "C", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "D", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "E", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "F", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "G", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "H", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "I", value: 0, y: 1}
];

var data5 = [
    {group: "A", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "B", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "C", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "D", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "E", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "F", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "G", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "H", value: 0, y: 1},
   {group: "I", value: 0, y: 1}
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Initialize the X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .padding(0.2);
var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

// Initialize the Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([ height, 0]);
var yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")

// functions that create / update the plot for data:

function update1(data) {

    
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
  .padding(0.2);
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)) 
    // Add Y axis

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([ height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

  u
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
}

function update2(data) {
    

    // X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    // Add Y axis

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-4, 4])
  .range([ height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

  u
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
}

function update3(data) {
    

    // X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    // Add Y axis

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([ height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

  u
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
}

function update4(data) {
    

    // X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    // Add Y axis

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([ height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

  u
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
}

function update5(data) {
    

    // X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    // Add Y axis

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([ height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

  u
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
}

// Initialize the plot with the first dataset
update1(data1)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code on update:

```js
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-4, 4])
  .range([ height, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Does not remove the previous axis `<g>` element and its contents.

Call:

```js
svg.selectAll("g.myYaxis").remove();
```

before appending a new one:

```js
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

The same happens with `axisBottom` as well.